# Responsive video page size

Tags: html, iframe

I am building a video page and I would like computer screens to show the 560X315, however, when I add the responsive code and dimensions as stated, the video is not responsive. When I remove the height/width dimensions, the video shrinks to almost thumbnail size.

```
<div class="videoWrapper embed-responsive-16by9" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;" data-videoid="10466530-95d9-d044-a0c4-be94a145d863"><iframe width="560" height="315" align="center" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o4PwOUDFhqM?list=PL9T_50FV6xCo5Y4Jr0vfSUaqrS0cZ6_yD" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" overflow="hidden"></iframe></div>
```

How do I get the video to display on the screens as the 560x315 but still be responsive?

Comment: Euhm ? Isn't that a contradication ? You either want the size you specify or you want a responsive design that correctly scales up/down. What do you exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: I see the confusion, but the problem is that when the video is responsive only, the size is about 2x4" on a regular display monitor. That is much too small. I want it to display at 560x315 on a monitor, but then scale down as the display decreases.